# Whats the difference between a Cog and an Extension in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In the discord.py documention, there are
Extensions: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/extensions.html
and Cogs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html
what is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions are files that are loaded, think of them as modules that the discord.py library imports when you call `load_extension`. After the import happens, a `setup` function is called, and is passed the `Bot` instance that it was loaded into....essentially `module.setup(bot)`. That is it, there is no more to extensions...typically this setup function calls `add_cog` which will be described next, however there is no *requirement* that they do so.

A Cog is a class that inherits from `commands.Cog` and is added to the bot's list of cogs through `add_cog`, these classes typically house commands and act as a "category" for these commands. It can also house listeners for events such as `on_message` or `on_member_join`, etc.

**TL;DR - Extensions are imported modules, cogs are classes**