# How can I use a bot class method (get_user()) in an extension? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The bot I have right now has quite a few commands, and I'm planning on moving several of them to extension files. Some of my commands require bot methods such as [`get_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_user), and I'm wondering how to implement that into extensions.

An example would be

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command()
async def bonk(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason = "being bad"):
    [command here]

    if not [condition]:
        dev = bot.get_user([myIDHere])
        await dev.send('Failed to update sheet')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_command(bonk)
```

Comment: We're now at discord.py Ver. 2, but the context has always included the bot reference (i.e., ctx.bot), so I think you can use the bot object in extensions without needing to make them cogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to extensions as cogs.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

class Example(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def bonk(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason = "being bad"):

    if not [condition]:
        dev = self.bot.get_user([myIDHere])
        await dev.send('Failed to update sheet')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Example(bot))
```

Then in your main.py, run this at the bottom. The top file must be in a folder called `cogs` if you haven't done so already.

```py
for cog_new in os.listdir("cogs"):
    if cog_new.endswith(".py"):
        try:
            cog = f"cogs.{cog_new.replace('.py', '')}"
            bot.load_extension(cog)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"{cog_new} can not be loaded: {e}")
```

Comment: I saw that the official documentation has separate pages for extensions and cogs, so I understood them to be different. And is it a bad practice to implement extensions without cogs?

Comment: @Shironats Cogs are basically extensions

Comment: They are not, they’re two totally different things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416372/whats-the-difference-between-a-cog-and-an-extension-in-discord-py?r=SearchResults

Comment: As Łukasz said above, Cogs and Extensions are NOT the same thing. You can have an extension without cogs and have cogs outside extensions. _Usually_ they are used together, but it is not mandatory.
Also, not a good idea to catch a bare `Exception` in the last part. Use a specific exception.