# How do I make a modular Discord bot in Python?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discord.py and I want every function to be a python file in itself. So I am creating the bot in `main.py` and importing it to the python files I require it in and creating the commands there. Then processing the commands using `bot.process_commands` in `main.py`. This however isn't working.

Is there a way I can even do this or does everything has to be in one file?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/extensions.html https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you don't have do everything in one file. You can use something called `Cogs`. You can watch the tutorials, read discord.py's official documentation or read my explanation.

**Cogs Explanation:**

You are just opening side-files that you can load to the bot. For example, a `help_commands.py` file that will hold all of the help commands.

To load the commands, they need to be grouped in a Cog class. You need to define a Main Class that inherits from the `Cog` class:

`class My_Help_Cog(commands.Cog):` `My_Help_Cog` will be our main `Cog` class that will be loaded to the bot.

Now we need a way to add this `Cog` to the bot. For that, discord.py uses a function called `setup`. In order to take your `Cog`, discord.py calls that `setup` function when you try to load the bot from the main file.

So let's define a `setup` function to the end of our code.

```
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(My_Help_Cog(Bot))
```

A whole example:

`help_commands.py`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class My_Help_Cog(commands.Cog, name="Help Commands"): # Our Main Cog class for writing our code. | name= is optional.
    def __init__(self, bot, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bot = bot # So we can access the bot in the class whenever we like.
    
    # All the code goes here, if you know OOP i assume you already understood.

def setup(bot): # Defining the setup so cog loader can understand what we want to add to the bot.
    bot.add_cog(My_Help_Cog(Bot) # Adding to the bot part.
```

However, `Cogs` have a caveat. When you're in `Cogs`, you are doing some things a little differently.

For example; when we define commands, we are no longer using the `@client.command()` (or `@bot.command()`) decorator to define commands.
Instead, you are using `@commands.command()` for the command decorator.

Same goes for the `events`, you now register to `events` via `@commands.Cog.listener()` instead of `@bot.event`.

Also, since we are in a `Class`, you need to pass `self` as your first parameter to everything in your `Class`.

So, we designed our `Cog` and the last part is just loading it on the main file. For this, you can use `bot`'s `load_extension` method in your main file:

```
bot.load_extension("cog's location.") # In our example, just "help_commands.py" for the location.
```

There are more methods for interacting with the cogs. A few of them:

- [Bot.load_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension)
- [Bot.reload_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.reload_extension)
- [Bot.unload_extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.unload_extension)

Comment: There's a difference between cogs and extensions, please do not mix them. [*Explanation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416372/whats-the-difference-between-a-cog-and-an-extension-in-discord-py/67416488#67416488)